# How do I check if every string in an array ends in a / or not

Tags: c, shell

I am trying to find out which strings in my array end in a /
but I am unsure how to check this

```
for(int k = 0; k < num_paths; k++) {
    path = malloc(strlen(paths[k]) + strlen(line) + 2);
    if(path == NULL) {
       exit(1);
    }
    if (paths[k] != '/') { // here is where I am trying to check
       strcpy(path, paths[k]);
       strcat(path, "/");
       strcat(path, commands[0]);
       if(access(path, X_OK) == 0) {
          execv(path, commands);
          error();
       }
    } else {
       strcpy(path, paths[k]);
       strcat(path, commands[0]);
       if(access(path, X_OK) == 0) {
          execv(path, commands);
          error();
       }
    }
    free(path);
}
```

I am expecting to find each string that doesnt have a /

Comment: Remember that `any_null_terminated_string[strlen(any_null_terminated_string)]` will be the null terminator. Now where could the last character of the string be?

Comment: I know how to do it with just one string but I am confused on when I am looping through them and I have an index. Just a single string is `path[strlen(path)-1] == '/'`

Comment: as per the observation it seems paths[k] is a sting, means this is a 2 dimentional array passed to this function. so as you have done above paths[k][strlen(paths[k]) -1] should be checked for the '/' like: if ( paths[k][strlen(paths[k]) -1] == '/') in the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now understand, first index to the string I want and then to the end of that string to see if there is a / or not.

Comment: You may not worry about the ending / since usually "path//command" works the same as "path/command".

Comment: Ya but I am not guaranteed a path with an ending /, so of there isn't one I need to add it.

Comment: @fnetma: if this path is given to any system operation like fopen(), execv() etc then there is no need for us to check and handle this, you can always have '/' concatenated always. so resulting string will have 1 or 2 '/' based on the input and system operations will take care as long as this path is present in the file system. But if this path is used  for some other local comparison with the database entry or for any local use then we may have to make sure of this handling. But for your purpose of execv this special handing not needed.